# Figuring out how to work with sets and lists

Tags: python, list, set, subset, intersection

I am using Python v3.3.2

I have researched this and still seem to have no luck, so I thought I would post.

I have a class file that creates an empty list and gathers values from another file and puts said values into a list. It does this twice so it creates two sets of numbers. For example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

A new list of numbers is thrown into the equation. For example:

```
[1, 5, 7, 3]
```

I helping determining if the new set of numbers is a subset of either of the two sets. For example:

```
[1, 5, 7, 3] is subset of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 5, 7, 3] is not a subset of [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I also need help determining the intersection of the two sets. For example:

```
[5, 6, 7] is the intersection of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] and [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The last thing I need help on is combining the two sets and removing duplicates. For example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] + [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Can anyone help me with any of these things?

Answer (score 3):

All the operations you mention are provided by the [`set`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#set) built-in data structure, or can be implemented in terms of its operations, you just need to take a look at the linked documentation. For example:

```
s1 = set([1, 5, 7, 3])
s2 = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

# is s1 a subset of s2?
s1.issubset(s2)
=> True

# set intersection
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]) & set([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
=> set([5, 6, 7])

# set union
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]) | set([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
=> set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Comment: Has any of this been changed in Python 3? The document you linked says 2.7.5, but I am using 3.3.2.

Comment: You might want to open the combo box in the left upper corner of that page.

Comment: @user2763179 no, the essential operations have not changed. I updated the link to point to Python 3's documentation.

Comment: I think I am getting confused because I have to have a list for each object in my class class that contains elements of the class. So how do I differentiate between the two different sets because I only have one list.

Comment: @user2763179 the question is not clear: all of the operations in the question require _two_ lists, but you say that you only have _one_ list. Don't get confused, wherever you're currently using a list, just change it to a set, that's all

Answer (score 1):

Use the [set data structure](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) in Python. You can freely convert lists to sets with `set()` and sets to lists with `list()`. sets in Python pretty much follow the definition of [mathematical sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29). This just means that all items in a set are distinct by definition. Converting a list to a set implicitly removes all duplicates.

Subset:

```
>>> a = [1, 5, 7, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> set(a).issubset(b)
True
>>> b = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> set(a).issubset(b)
False
```

Intersection:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> b = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> list(set(a).intersection(b))
[5, 6, 7]
```

Combining the two sets and removing duplicates:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> b = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> list(set().union(a, b))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: I think I am getting confused because I have to have a list for each object in my class class that contains elements of the class. So how do I differentiate between the two different sets because I only have one list.

Comment: @user2763179 What do you mean differentiate between the two different sets? Which two sets are you talking about?

Comment: Like in one of my files it does a while loop that sets the variable 'first' equal to 0-9, then does another while loop that sets the variable 'second' equal to 5-14. Then it creates another variable called 'third' that is an empty list and appends 4 numbers and then calls a method from my class to determine if 'third' is a subset of 'first' or 'second'. In my class file I have a constructor method (__init__) that does not take any arguments but initializes an empty list (myList = []).

Comment: @user2763179 Hmm sorry I read everything you wrote but I still don't understand what you're having trouble with. Maybe post your code in a different question? :)

Comment: I'll just add that when using `set.issubset()` it doesn't require the other iterable to be a set - so you can use `set(a).issubset(b)` and the combining the two sets and removing duplicates can be done as `set().union(a, b)` to avoid the `+` for the lists

Comment: @JonClements I edited my `issubset` example to avoid using the `set` constructor. Anyways I'm aware of `union` but I like the `+` syntax better. It makes more sense to me. Thanks for the first bit though, I did not know that. :)

Comment: @shashsnk okie dokies - just mentioning the union as it doesn't need to create a temporary list

Comment: @JonClements I guess you're right. Creating a temporary list might be inefficient. You've convinced me. I edited my answer. Thanks.